# Centrar elementos

Tags: css, css3

Hola tengo bastantes problemas con algo bastante básico. Conseguir centrar elementos, y en este caso siendo muy sencillo, no lo consigo.

```css
.Portada {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#Fondo-Portada {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
}

#Logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#Frase-Presentacion {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#Btn-Ready {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border-color: #b00000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Portada">
  <img id="Fondo-Portada" src="Img/Fondo-Presentacion.jpg" alt="">

  <img id="Logo" src="Img/logo70px.png" alt="Logo">

  <p id="Frase-Presentacion"> Hola, soy Carlos. Y diseño y construyo </p>

  <input type="button" id="Btn-Ready" value="I'm ready">
</div>
```

¿Como centraría la imagen logo y el botón? Imagino que ambas es lo mismo.

Gracias!!

Comment: Que elementos deseas centrar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text-align:center;` al `div` y nada más.

```css
.Portada {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align:center;
}

#Fondo-Portada {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
}

#Logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#Frase-Presentacion {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#Btn-Ready {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border-color: #b00000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Portada">
  <img id="Fondo-Portada" src="Img/Fondo-Presentacion.jpg" alt="">

  <img id="Logo" src="Img/logo70px.png" alt="Logo">

  <p id="Frase-Presentacion"> Hola, soy Carlos. Y diseño y construyo </p>

  <input type="button" id="Btn-Ready" value="I'm ready">
</div>
```